# JSTL stringFormat...set to a VAR?

Tags: jstl

Hello I have something like this:

```
  <c:when test='${results.fieldNames[rowStatus.index] == "NSN"}'>
                <fmt:formatNumber value="${cell}" pattern="${commas_with_no_decimal_pattern}" var="tArr"/>
                </c:when>
```

Where Im setting a formatted # to `var="tArr"`.  I want to use a string formatter and set it to `var="tArr"`.  But I only know how to set it up like this:

```
<ctl:stringFormat format="@@@@-@@-@@@-@@@@">${dispVal}</ctl:stringFormat>
```

How can I set this formatted string to a var?

Comment: had to set `var` as a property in the `ctl:stringFormat` tld

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to set `var` as a property in the `ctl:stringFormat` tld